# Excel Formula || How to count occurrences of a value in column

Tags: excel, count, cell

Need some help in figuring out an formula to count the number of times a value is listed in a column. I will try and explain the requirement below.

The below image show sample of data set.

[image: Data Set]

The requirement is to list out issues and actions per customer.
As you can see, even from values clustered in cell, we need to find out individual unique values and then map it against the adjacent column or columns.

[image: Clustered data]

Comment: How should actions get mapped? A parallel table to issues? What if KFC has another "Server got hung" issue? Should "Server got hung" show twice?

Comment: it would be easier parsing the data in some programming language, e.g Python or VBA... possible with Excel formulas with a lot of helper columns, though way more complicated than what I am willing to wrap my mind around - it would start with `=LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2, "," ,""))` and a running sum in the input table, continue with a `=ROW()` counter in the output table and then some `=MID(...headache inducing calculations...)`

Comment: You could do this using Excel's `Power Query` in Excel 2010+ (aka `Get&Transform` in 2016).  You could also write a VBA routine.

Comment: Yeh since its already in excel, and if you're ignoring Actions, just parse out Customer Name, set the isse to each customer name with partial relative ref and transpose vertically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It just need an extra sheet/table to execute..

try :

```
A1 = a,b,c
A2 = b,c
A3 = c,b,a
A4 = c,a
A5 = b
B1 = ss
B2 = ss
B3 = dd
B4 = dd
B5 = ss
D1 = a
E1 = b
F1 = c
C7 = ss
C8 = dd

D2 =IF(FIND(D$1,$A2,1)>0,1,"") drag until F6

D7 =COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$6,$C7,D$2:D$6,1) drag until F8
```

D7:F8 will be your desired results. Happy trying.

Comment: This is great .. Absolutely as intended. I am new to forum and not sure on how to mark it as answered but if admin can help and guide to close, as the query is resolved.

Comment: Glad to know it helps.. Appreciate if you can 'accept' the answer like [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) . It will remove this question from the 'unanswered' question list. ( :

Comment: added a correction `D2:D6` become `D$2:D$6` in the last formula..  sorry, just noticed it.