# can i use index match to do wildcards of multiple text in a string

Tags: excel, string, text, indexing, match

i have seen a few discussions about using wildcards in excel but it seems to cover partial text as a single word: [Finding partial text in range, return an index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15566316/finding-partial-text-in-range-return-an-index)

i want to be able to Index and MATCH by finding a word in string for example

D4: "bob jim fred gary"

=INDEX(D7:D10,MATCH("*"&D4&"*",C7:C10,0))
(please note i have also tried(D4&"*") and other variations of this)

C9: fred D: yay

This doesnt seem to work using range of wildcard options?

Is there a way to match a segment of text in a string to do INDEX MATCH or produce data from a partial text match that isnt a full string?

thank you for your expertise!

Comment: "D4: "bob jim fred gary" <-- I suggest to do : `=iferror(<IndexMatch1>,"")+iferror(<IndexMatch2>,"")+iferror(<IndexMatch3>,"")+iferror(<IndexMatch>,"")`  || "Is there a way to match a segment of text in a string to do INDEX MATCH or produce data from a partial text match that isnt a full string?" <-- you mean like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51447769/excel-formula-how-to-count-occurrences-of-a-value-in-column/51451185#51451185) ?

Comment: This ref may be [usefull](https://chandoo.org/wp/comprehensive-guide-excel-vlookup/)..