# How to count from an looked up range in excel

Tags: excel, countif

I have a pivot table that has a row for a set of cities. I want to count the number of cities in a certain state. It's not wanted to include the state in the pivot table (although that would make things simpler).

I tried using the following formula:

```
={countif(index(city_ref[state], match(G15:G30,city_ref[city_name],0)),"=CA")}
```

Where:

> - `city_ref` is a table that has at least the columns `[city_name]` and `[state]`
> - `G15:G30` are the rows of the pivot table

The data looks like this (simplified):

`city_ref`:

```
city_name   | state
====================
Los Angeles | CA
Seattle     | WA
Portland    | OR
etc.
```

`G15:G30`:

```
     city_name
     ===========
G15: Los Angeles
G16: Seattle
     etc. (but not all of city_ref)
```

I do realize that you could include the state in a pivot table but a) that's not wanted (even hiding it) and b) there is other, dis-related data that when the state is included the pivot table makes additional rows which messes up the count.

The `index match` lookup seems to return an array if used on its own; if I use the `fill handle` it does create an array of cells with the lookup values between `G15:G30`. However including this in `countif` does not seem to do anything.

In the help page for `countif` that I have in excel (unfortunately I cannot find an online reference to link to) it says that `range` (the first argument) can be an array.

I want to be able to take an arbitrary array of values, look them up in another table and count the ones that match my criteria.

Comment: Can you please post samples of your files/tables, and desired output, please?

Comment: Please [edit] your question include a sample of your input data (text, not pictures preferably) and an example of your desired output. See [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: @Jbowman, girlvsdata, tks. I expanded this

Comment: How do you propose to handle same city names in different states, eg:  
`Richmond & Arlington in TX and VA  
Gainesville in FL and in VA  
Charleston in WVa and in SC  
Memphis in TN and in KY  
Nashville in TN and in KY`?

Comment: What you try to achieve is somewhat similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51447769/excel-formula-how-to-count-occurrences-of-a-value-in-column/51451185#51451185) question for me.. Please share if the proposed example does/doesn't fit your need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this ?

[image]

`{=SUM((IFERROR(MATCH($D$2:$D$7,INDEX(IF($B$2:$B$13=$F$2,$A$2:$A$13),),0),0)>0)*1)}`

Comment: That works. Two questions: 1. I didn't notice any difference between including the `index` or not (just having the `if` by itself) and 2. how do the "empty" parameters like `,)` work? What are the rules behind this (probably easiest if you provide a link instead of answering this in a comment)?

Comment: @4lackof you are very correct, the index part is no necessary, I noticed after posting and did not edit the answer. for your second question, not setting any value to the row argument makes the function return the array of values indexed. You'll find more details here :[INDEX function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-a5dcf0dd-996d-40a4-a822-b56b061328bd) in the "REMARKS" section

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just make a copy of the PivotTable, add a Slicer so users can filter it on a particular State, and add the State field to the Values area so that it gets counted? Seems counter productive to point a formula at PivotTable 1 when you could simply have PivotTable2 do the sum by State.